# Database Request with entry variable as argument

Tags: templating, entries

I am new to Craft CMS and although it is quite simple to use I am stuck on this one. I have 3 sections ('books', 'games', 'movies') and want to do the following:

```
{% for sub_entry in craft.entries('{{ entry.sectionName }}').find() %}
```

The problem is that it gives me all sub_entries not just the ones within a specific section i.e. `entry.sectionName`? If I print out `{{ entry.sectionName }}` on my website it gives me the correct sectionNames but somehow I can not pass it on to the for loop?

How do I solve this?
Kind regards,
Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Craft/Twig, you'll never need to nest `{{` and `{%` tags inside of each other.

So:

```
{% for sub_entry in craft.entries('{{ entry.sectionName }}').find() %}
```

Should be:

```
{% for sub_entry in craft.entries(entry.sectionName).find() %}
```

Answer (score 1):

hmm, wat do you mean with sub_entries? As a general pointer I would do it like this:

```
{% set books = craft.entries.section('books') %}
```

and then loop over the books.

To get back to your question, I would suggest moving all the different sections into 1 channel with multiple types in it. For example:

Channel: Media

Types:

- Books
- Games
- Movies

Then you can query them like this:

```
{% set books = craft.entries.section('media').type(['books']) %}

{% for entry in books %}
    <h2>{{entry.title}}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

More info on types [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries#entry-types)